# UISwitch on click goes back to previous page in xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

In my application, one of the `view controllers` is behaving strangely.
When I click anywhere of that `vc`
it takes me to the previous `vc`.
I have checked every line of code and also checked the segue but found nothing.
Is it a `bug`?

Edit:And sometimes it just works ok!

Comment: Can you post your code, it is kinda impossible to say

Comment: Well it's a pretty big code..which part do you want?

Comment: Well, is there some relevant code for going back to previous vc? To you have some thing like pop, dismiss or something like that? Are you using autolayout so the back button sometimes overlays your screen?

Comment: nothing I have done for going back to previous vc in coding, nor i used autolayout...but i used an UIAlertController...but I don't see it as the cause of my problem